# Split Multiple Polygons into equal squares?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, batch, splitting

I have 1 single shapefile of about 70k square polygons in a grid.  I want to run a process/tool/script to split all 70k polygons into 4 equal parts.  The polygons are contiguous, so each polygon only has 4 vertices.  Basically I have a shapefile of sections for a sate, and I want to split it into 1/4 sections so each original square section is broken into 4 equal 1/4 parts.

How can I split all 70,000 contiguous square polygons at once with only 4 vertices each into 4 equal parts to create 4 polygons within each original polygon?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your polygon dataset is a regular grid of polygons, rather than square polygons randomly placed everywhere then this can be achieved with a simple model to create a fishnet then retrospectively delete out the polygons you do not need.

The model to achieve this is this:

[image: Model]

Here is final output applied to the original grid (red outlines):

[image: UK grid quartered]

Answer (score 2):

Here is set of ArcGIS Tools specifically built to subdivide Public Land Survey Sections. One of the tools will create Quarter Sections. http://ianbroad.com/creating-quarter-quarter-section-grid-python/.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed!  Thank you for posting your response, and assisting me in what could have been a very daunting task!

Comment: Not sure why that last guy didn't upvote, but this tool is perfect.  With irregular grids (not North/South), fishnets aren't ideal and this tool saved me having to go into the weeds with a custom model.  Thanks!